# problem with cron job java spring boot in zk-spring framework for a website

Tags: java, spring, cron, zk

i'm trying to using cron job to give information about connection to server, but i allready tried any method and when i'm running java file as application my cron job script is not running at all.

```
@Component
public class checkData {
    @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * *")
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("test cron job");
    }
```

and i tried to running it in another class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("spring.enable.scheduling")


 public class test{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JRException {
        SpringApplication.run(test.class);

    }
    }
}
```

when i'm running test class as java application it's get error java class not found. is there something wrong in my script ? thank's

Comment: You aren't running anything. You only have a main that prints something to the console, your applicaiton isn't going to be started with this.

Comment: how should i running it? i think cron job is automatically running without stopping when i run an java class.

Comment: i try to running in main using SpringApplication.run(test.class);, it get error class not found

Comment: Currently you aren't running anything. If you get a classnotfound, fix that. Removing that line isn't fixing it.

Comment: with zk-spring are you referring to _org.zkoss.zkspringboot/zkspringboot-starter_ ?

Comment: i'm refering to springboot, not zkspringboot-starter. i will try to refering to zkspringboot-starter. thanks

Comment: well it's allready work without refering zkspringboot. i just need a new xml thank import it to application-config.xml. and it run based on cron that i setting. thank's for the help